# What's difference between 'hardly' and 'rarely'?

Tags: word-choice

What's difference between 'hardly' and 'rarely'?
To the questions like, "How often do you go clothes shopping?"
Should I answer as,"Rarely" or "Hardly"?

Comment: "Rarely" or "hardly ever".

Comment: or ***hardly every day** (but rarely less than twice a week)*

Answer (score 2):

Hardly has a nuance of being difficult to do.

Rarely has a nuance of very isolated occurrences in time.

Seldom is possibly closer to what you want to convey in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rarely in this context, but not hardly.

However, "rarely and " hardly ever" as frequency adverbs can be used  in the sense of "not often".  So these are interchangeable.

You can use rarely or hardly ever as follows:

How often do you go shopping for clothes? Rarely/Hardly ever.